# Is there a way to open a dropbox link locally (mac app)?

Tags: dropbox

I use dropbox for businesses, all of us have the mac app installed. Is there a way for me to copy the path of a folder/file and share it with other people on the same account, in such way that the link would open locally, and not on the web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Dropbox doesn't offer a way to link to local files across users like this, but we'll consider it a feature request.